# Send data file from client UDP ipv6 to the server

Tags: c, file, sockets, udp

I try to send a file data size of around 100MB from the client to the server in UDP ipv6.

the server I  think it works well but the client I cannot figure out why I cannot send the file.

When I try to "sendto" I got the message: perror("[-]Error in sending the file. in UDP CLIENT")"

here is my code:

```
 void client() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[65536];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(P);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int n, len;
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
    char data[SIZE] = {0};

    while (fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        if (sendto(sockfd, data, sizeof(data),
                   MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                   sizeof(servaddr)) == -1) {
            perror("[-]Error in sending file. in UDP CLIENT");
            exit(1);
        }
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *) buffer, 65536,
                 MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                 &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);

    close(sockfd);
}
```